# Session expire issue when submitting form in php

Tags: php, session

I have set session timeout value 5 mins(300 sec). Below is the code.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 300)) {
  // last request was more than 5 minates ago
  session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}           

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

I have a form and it will take more than 5 mins to filled it. When user submit it session get expired.

**How I can maintain the session expiration time at the time of filling a form?**

Comment: Does this tend to pose some light on your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can send an ajax call to the server via one of the many javascript events associated with your form.

Comment: Thanks, as I understood I have to send ajax call when click on submit. And set this `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();` then after submit a form. I will try this. Thank you.